# Magento 2 Gift text message module not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to enable and show the Gift message module on product detail pages in Magento 2.3.1.

Thanks

Comment: Gift message will work on shopping cart by default. That means the product is needed to add to cart. Could you explain more details about your idea?

Comment: I already added product in cart but there are no gift message option showing.

Comment: Did you enable it in admin STORES > Configuration  > Sales > Gift Options > Allow Gift Messages for Order Items?

Comment: Yes i was made this changes.

Comment: But, where do you want to add the gift text message? on product details page or shopping cart page? The config is for cart page.

Comment: Actually i want to show on both pages( Product details and cart).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96339/discussion-between-ketan-and-khoa-truongdinh).